# Django Rest Framework: Get field name from model definition

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Within the Django Rest framework documentation it is suggested to declare the "field" list explicitly to avoid providing the data of new columns just by adding them to the model which may contain sensitive information.

The field list is an array of strings, containing the field ids. To avoid declaring field ids, which actually do not exist in the model (e.g. typos or changed models) I tried to declare the list using object references - but always end up with "DeferredAttribute: object has no attribute ".

I have read something that meta information is not available in objects and that you could solve that by defininig your own Meta class using [Object._meta.get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/) and store it in the class, but I thought there might be a simpler/more elegant way (and I do now know, how, in detail ;-)).

Example:

```
    class Samples(models.Model):
    # Meta data, primarily used in AdminSite.
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Samples')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Samples')

    samples_boolfield = models.BooleanField
    samples_textfield = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
class SamplesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SamplesSerializer
    queryset = Samples.objects.all()
```

serializers.py:

Version 1, which does not show any errors in pyCharm or makemigrations, but calling the API reults in "TypeError at /api/samples/: argument of type 'DeferredAttribute' is not iterable":

```
class SamplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Samples
        fields = (
            'id',
            Samples.samples_boolfield,
            Samples.samples_textfield,
        )
```

Version 2, which does not show any errors in pyCharm, but makemigrations fails with "DeferredAttribute: object has no attribute **name**":

```
class SamplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Samples
        fields = (
            'id',
            Samples.samples_boolfield.__name__,
            Samples.samples_textfield.__name__,
        )
```

Version 3, which does not show any errors in pyCharm, but makemigrations fails with "DeferredAttribute: object has no attribute get_attname":

```
class SamplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Samples
        fields = (
            'id',
            Samples.samples_boolfield.get_attname(),
            Samples.samples_textfield.get_attname(),
        )
```

Is there a way to declare the field list using object references (so that it fails e.g. in pyCharm/during compilation)?

Thank you for your feedback.

Regards,
HerrB92

Comment: why do you need this? Just use  fields = ['samples_boolfield', 'samples_textfield'] or exclude = ('field1', )

Comment: Change code only at one location (code more reliably).

If you use fields = ['my_fieldname'] and the model has no field my_fieldname,
you have renamed the field later (and forgot to update fields as well) or
you mistyped (e.g. ['my__fieldname'], then I would like to see this during development/makemigrations and not by testing the API.